# Error when installing libcxx and libcxxabi rpm - requires: /usr/sbin/ldconfig - Centos7

Tags: glibc

I can't seem to find any articles with the following two libc errors. I've also tried the following commands with no luck...

yum install glibc*

yum install yum-utils
yum update yum*
package-cleanup --dupes
package-cleanup --cleandupes

rm /etc/ld.so.cache
ldconfig

Full printout of yum update command

```
    [root@test etc]# yum update
    Loaded plugins: langpacks, rhnplugin
    This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
    Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.17-325.el7_9 will be updated
    ---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.17-326.el7_9 will be an update
    ---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.17-325.el7_9 will be updated
    ---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.17-326.el7_9 will be an update
    ---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.17-325.el7_9 will be updated
    ---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.17-326.el7_9 will be an update
    ---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.17-325.el7_9 will be updated
    ---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.17-326.el7_9 will be an update
    ---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7 will be updated
    ---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.66.1.el7 will be an update
    --> Processing Dependency: /usr/sbin/ldconfig for package: libcxx-11.0.1-1.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: /usr/sbin/ldconfig for package: libcxxabi-11.0.1-1.el7.x86_64
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error: Package: libcxx-11.0.1-1.el7.x86_64 (installed)
    Requires: /usr/sbin/ldconfig
    Removing: glibc-2.17-325.el7_9.x86_64 (@spacewalk_centos7)
    Not found
    Updated By: glibc-2.17-326.el7_9.x86_64 (spacewalk_centos7)
    Not found
    Error: Package: libcxxabi-11.0.1-1.el7.x86_64 (installed)
    Requires: /usr/sbin/ldconfig
    Removing: glibc-2.17-325.el7_9.x86_64 (@spacewalk_centos7)
    Not found
    Updated By: glibc-2.17-326.el7_9.x86_64 (spacewalk_centos7)
    Not found
[root@test etc]# rpm -qa | grep glibc
glibc-common-2.17-325.el7_9.x86_64
glibc-2.17-325.el7_9.x86_64
glibc-devel-2.17-325.el7_9.x86_64
glibc-headers-2.17-325.el7_9.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/yum.conf` and see if you exclude any of the packages that might be blocking your installation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any exclusions.

```
# in /etc/yum.repos.dc
http_caching=packages
[/etc/yum.conf][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wImmA.png
```